# PHP script that does not reveal real path generates download with ".php" extension

Tags: php, file, header

A file called "transfer.php" should offer a file for download. Instead of the download, it offers a file with a ".php" of the same file size as the original file. Did I get the header wrong?

Thanks!

```
<?php
session_start();

$path = $_SESSION['myvar'];

$mm_type = "application/octet-stream";

header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: ".$mm_type);
header("Content-Length: ".(string)(filesize($path)) );
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");

readfile($path); // outputs the content of the file

exit();
```

Comment: `application/octet-stream` why?

Comment: Lose the `\n` in your `Content-Transfer-Encoding`.

Comment: Can it not be used to cover a variety of types like pdf's, ppt's etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I originally suggested removing the trailing unpaired quote in the disposition header ..

The file name [should be enclosed in quotes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) (thanks Wrikken!). In the posted code the first quote is missing. Using `'` for the first string makes the pairing (or lack of) more clear:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($path) . '"');
```

Comment: There's also an extra `\n` in the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

Comment: Thanks removing the extra quotes fixed the problem. Is it ok to use "octet-stream" for a variety of files?

Comment: Close: `filename=\"".basename($path).'"');` would probably be more appropriate. ([the filename should be quoted string](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks .. that's basically my answer now.

Comment: @Levi It's been awhile, but I *think* I remember it depending on browser itself and affect the default actions it would take .. but all the details allude me. That would make a good *additional* question.